# Duplicate logs "session expired" in tomcat cluster

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing

I have two nodes Tomtsat 7. As a manager used org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager. On each node runs HttpSessionListenerImpl. In the method sessionDestroyed logged some data session. Can I determine in the method sessionDestroyed  that the session is  primary for the node? It's need to write log only on primary node.